# Draw form isolated using PDFBOX

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to draw an XObject from type form in a new PDF page, I did the following:

```
this.cell = (PDFormXObject) xobject;
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -cell.getBBox().getLowerLeftX(),-cell.getBBox().getLowerLeftY()));
contentStream.drawForm(cell);
contentStream.close();
document.addPage(page);
document.save("D://temp//blankPage.pdf");
document.close();
```

The result is as desired, but the xobject has larger border with empty areas, I only need to isolate the internal box with (which I add yellow border to it), here is a ss:
[image]

Comment: Could you link to the source PDF?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b0595af6db34aced583be276ca59834120180403164224/5f4c94

Comment: Can you share enough code to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: You didn't tell which form object you were using, but having a look at `Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Resources/XObject/Fm27/Resources/XObject/Fm28` one can see that there is a rotation and translation before the next inner level is shown: 0 -1 1 0 1049.48 -2306.118 cm. I wonder if you'd have to do that as well... (it's getting late here so I can't end that thought)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am trying to draw FM2, never mind the rotation for now, here is the output PDF https://wetransfer.com/downloads/47fe31f59714b409a4873c1a08aa830520180404031447/d07c7c

Comment: @mkl I will when I am at my disk, sure.

Comment: Ok, I looked at your PDFs. It looks like these XObjects simply do have a lot of white space around the interesting content. If you are working with a single such source document only, you could determine the appropriate offsets by trial and error. If instead you'll have to determine the actual content extent for arbitrary XObject sources, you could try using a `PDFStreamEngine` (or descendant class) instance to determine the bounding box of the actual content, or you could render the XObject as a bitmap image and derive the bounding box from that image.

Comment: @mkl indeed, I already played with it a bit and using the PDFStreamEngine, I managed to find the bounding box of the actual content, but I didn't complete the work, once it is done, I will update my answer.